# Is it possible to have one comment for property and private variable

Tags: c#, properties, comments

Hello everyone my question is very simple.

```
/// <summary>
/// a description here. for internal use
/// </summary>
private A _Owner;
/// <summary>
/// Same description also here. for outside use
/// </summary>
public A Owner
{
    get { return _Owner; }
    set { _Owner = value; }
}
```

Is there  a way to avoid writing the same comment twice? It is just a nuisance.

Comment: Is it even nescessary to write a comment for your private field?

Comment: In this case I usually omit a description of private field.

Comment: I always only comment on the public field.

Comment: @JeroenMoonen Well this class is a facade implementation of a larger game engine functinality both the number of properties and private variables are large. Thats why I also need comments for private variables. For example there is a private variable called _renderDelta to use this private variable you need to know if it is milliseconds or seconds, if there was a comment on it it would help greatly. Also I hate magicnumbers without comments on why it is in a such way.

Comment: Good answers. Thanks for guidance I have selected the answer with highest votes at time. It seems there is not a simple way other then using auto implemented properties.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly, note that you *do not need* intellisense comments for private members, including fields. So you could just *remove the first comment*. If the meaning of the field isn't obvious from the name, then you haven't named it appropriately.

Secondly, for most simple properties, you could remove the explicit field declaration completely...

```
/// <summary>a description here</summary>
public A Owner {get;set;}
```

Comment: Dear mark altough I agree with you about naming conventions please consider magicnumber situation and where you can need extra info for a private field such as I explained in the comments of my question. That is a valid and acceptable situation for needing private filed comment information.

Answer (score 5):

It's not. But commenting the property should suffice, because the private members are not shown outside of your class. So just comment your property.

Answer (score 4):

If it's just a straight view onto a backing field, just use an auto property to avoid the duplication.

```
/// <summary>
/// just use an autoprop
/// </summary>
public A Owner
{
    get;set;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use **[Auto implemented properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384054.aspx)** and then you can specify a single XML comment for the property.

```
/// <summary>
/// Same description also here. for outside use
/// </summary>
public A Owner
{
get; set;
}
```

But if you are doing something with the private field in your get or set then you have to specify XML comments twice.

One more thing, **You probably have to specify XML comments just for the property**, since that is exposed outside the class, not your public field.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to avoid this, as intelisense links written comment to a code artifact found. In your case you have **2** of them:

- one is a `property`.
- another is a `field`.

So *in your case*, you would need to write it twice,  or, as spender suggested, use auto property and define it once.